# I want to know a genric method for scrolling in appium java

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, generics, appium

I want to scroll through the homepage of this and related other applications for which i need a generic scroll method

[image]

Comment: what you did try so far

Comment: There are dozens (at least) of questions on this topic with the Appium tag.  Have you tried searching here for an answer first?  I know I've posted at least one answer in the not too distant past.

Comment: I have tried and tested all of the solutions that I found but none of them worked. Kindly post the code that you think would work for this

Answer (score 0):

I was sure I had posted this in the past and did not want to re-post it, but I cannot seem to locate it, so I'm posting here now.

Below is a set of methods which will allow you to scroll up, down, left, and right, preceded by a summary (generic) scroll method called by each of the preceding four directional scroll methods.

```
/**
 * This method scrolls based upon the passed parameters
 * @author Bill Hileman
 * @param int startx - the starting x position
 * @param int starty - the starting y position
 * @param int endx - the ending x position
 * @param int endy - the ending y position
 */
public void scroll(int startx, int starty, int endx, int endy) {

    TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(driver);

    touchAction.longPress(PointOption.point(startx, starty))
               .moveTo(PointOption.point(endx, endy))
               .release()
               .perform();

}

/**
 * This method does a swipe upwards
 * @author Bill Hileman
 * @throws Exception
 */
public void scrollDown() throws Exception {

    //The viewing size of the device
    Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();

    //Starting y location set to 80% of the height (near bottom)
    int starty = (int) (size.height * 0.80);
    //Ending y location set to 20% of the height (near top)
    int endy = (int) (size.height * 0.20);
    //x position set to mid-screen horizontally
    int startx = (int) size.width / 2;

    scroll(startx, starty, startx, endy);

}

/**
 * This method does a swipe left
 * @author Bill Hileman
 * @throws Exception
 */
public void swipeLeft() throws Exception {

    //The viewing size of the device
    Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();

    //Starting x location set to 95% of the width (near right)
    int startx = (int) (size.width * 0.95);
    //Ending x location set to 5% of the width (near left)
    int endx = (int) (size.width * 0.05);
    //y position set to mid-screen vertically
    int starty = size.height / 2;

    scroll(startx, starty, endx, starty);

}

/**
 * This method does a swipe right
 * @author Bill Hileman
 * @throws Exception
 */
public void swipeRight() throws Exception {

    //The viewing size of the device
    Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();

    //Starting x location set to 5% of the width (near left)
    int startx = (int) (size.width * 0.05);
    //Ending x location set to 95% of the width (near right)
    int endx = (int) (size.width * 0.95);
    //y position set to mid-screen vertically
    int starty = size.height / 2;

    scroll(startx, starty, endx, starty);

}

/**
 * This method does a swipe downwards
 * @author Bill Hileman
 * @throws Exception
 */
public void scrollUp() throws Exception {

    //The viewing size of the device
    Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();

    //Starting y location set to 20% of the height (near bottom)
    int starty = (int) (size.height * 0.20);
    //Ending y location set to 80% of the height (near top)
    int endy = (int) (size.height * 0.80);
    //x position set to mid-screen horizontally
    int startx = size.width / 2;

    scroll(startx, starty, startx, endy);

}
```

Comment: If all you want to do is scroll, you should call scrollDown which in turn calls scroll with the correct parameters to scroll from 80% of the screen height to 20% of the screen height.  Look at the code example and if you want to change the percentages, feel free to do so, but I've found the ones I've hard-coded to be sufficient.

Comment: Should I put all of these methods in a separate class and then call it in the main or let them be separate methods?

Comment: what values should I give in int startx, int starty, int endx, int endy?

Comment: These methods should be in the same class that has your driver, in my case called "driver"  I have one class called AppiumUtils which contain all my appium helper functions.  I'm not sure why your original comment to this answer has somehow moved to the bottom of the list of comments, but regarding to values, see my first comment.

Comment: when ever i call the methods, scroll, scrollDown etc it asks me to change the methods to static and throw declaration. And after running the test case i get error like: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Coordinate [x=720.0, y=1184.0] is outside of element rect: [0,0][720,1184] (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds THIS ERROR GOES ON AND ON

Comment: That's fine, simply add static to their declarations and throws exception as well if needed.  I avoid writing static methods like the plague, but if you're coding static stuff elsewhere, you might have to make the methods static as well.

Comment: What is your new code?  Where did you wind up putting these methods?  How are you invoking them?  Which method(s) are you calling?  I know this code works because I use it myself.

Comment: Im calling scroll(0,0,720,1184);
   scrollDown();
   swipeLeft();
   swipeRight();
   scrollUp(); in the main method and these methods are outside the main method

Comment: Did you look at the examples I gave to see how and why I am determining the parameters for each scroll?  Do you understand how an x/y coordinate system works?  There's a reason I select the specific x and y coordinates for each swipe/scroll motion.  I suggest you only use them unless you want to risk problems like you're encountering.  The coordinates calculated in the swipe methods are determined based on screen size and percentages.  You're telling it to swipe from upper left corner to lower right corner (extreme edges).

Comment: this is my code, i have removed the basics because the characters were increasing but that's how my code looks like :


public class firstpro { static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = null;   scroll(0,0,720,1184);scrollDown(); swipeLeft();swipeRight();scrollUp();}
 
public static void scroll(int startx, int starty, int endx, int endy) {}

public static void scrollDown() throws Exception {}
public static void swipeLeft() throws Exception {}
public static void swipeRight() throws Exception {}
public static void scrollUp() throws Exception {}}

Comment: I'm a beginner so its hard to understand can you tell how to call these methods? or in which sequence and what values to give in the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Below are the generic methods for horizontal and vertical scroll in appium using java.

```
public static MobileElement horizontalScroll(String selector) {
MobileElement element = (MobileElement) driver.findElement(MobileBy
        .AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).setAsHorizontalList()
        .scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains(\""+ selector + "\"));"));
        return element;
    }

public static MobileElement verticalScroll(String selector) {
MobileElement element = (MobileElement) driver.findElement(MobileBy
        .AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector())
        .scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains(\""+ selector + "\"));"));
        return element;
    }
```